# Realtek sound does not show anywhere even through it is one

Tags: windows-10, audio

Realtek sound control does not show up anywhere, i got sound and if you plug in headphones a dialog box will pop up but there isnt anywhere to change the sound settings can you fix this problem so i can see the settings and change them?

Answer (score 0):

If your audio card *is* a Realtek one, I suggest you go on their website to find the most up-to-date drivers and helper programs for it. From what I understand of your problem, it is precisely what is missing.

Alternatively, there's the website [driverscloud.com](http://driverscloud.com) which will detect exactly what sound card you use and will give you download links for drivers and helper programs. It's free and saved my life many times.

Comment: it still dosent work it just removed the headphone pop up